# P420 Hewlett Packard RAID controller reporting identical physicaldrive in all HDD disks

Tags: linux, hardware-raid, sas

Followed this article to install HP Smart Storage Utilities on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

https://www.jimmdenton.com/hp-raid-tools-ubuntu/

I have an UNYKAch Server Rack Hot Swap 4U 24 Bay. I am using a Hewlett Packard P420 RAID controller with a SAS expander. Right now I have 8-4TB HDD disks connected to the backplate. This is the current status reported by the controller:

```
# ssacli ctrl all show config
Smart Array P420 in Slot 4                (sn: PDSXK0BRH5W034)
   HP SAS Expander Card at Port 1I, Box 1, OK
   Port Name: 1I
   Port Name: 2I
   Unassigned

      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)

   Expander 380  (WWID: 500143801174B426, Port: 1I, Box: 1)
   HP SAS Expander Card SEP 378  (WWID: 500143801174B425, Port: 1I, Box: 1)
   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 379  (WWID: 5001438028F5637F)
```

As you can see, the tool is reporting "physicaldrive 1I:1:0" in all disks.

I don't have any experience with RAID controllers, this is my first time. But looking at the initial post, I expected to see something like that:

```
  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:7 (port 1I:box 1:bay 7, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:8 (port 1I:box 1:bay 8, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:10 (port 1I:box 1:bay 10, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:11 (port 1I:box 1:bay 11, SATA HDD, 2 TB, OK)
```

where every single HDD receives a unique physicaldrive in sequence.

Do you know what can be wrong with that? Should I install some missing HP firmware?

Answer (score 0):

I found a firmware available here:

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/swd/detail?swItemId=MTX_42b6aa58956a438aa85bd73d0f#tab3

Downloaded file hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1.x86_64.rpm and converted to .deb using alien. Then installed it in my filesystem:

```
# dpkg -L hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/.cpq_package.inc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/.hpsetup
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/746374726C00.firmware.bin.fw
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/747365700069443232323073620076312E303200.Baz-102.fuf.fw
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/CP033363.xml
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/d2220sb.bin.fw
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/hpsetup
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7-8.32-1.1/libhpsetup.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-scexe-compat
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hp-scexe-compat/CP033363.scexe
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7
/usr/share/doc/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/hp-firmware-smartarray-46a4d957a7/copyright
```

Then executed the binary "CP033363.scexe"

```
# ./CP033363.scexe 
Supplemental Update / Online ROM Flash Component for Linux (x64) - Smart Array P220i, P222, P420i, P420, P421, P721m, and P822 (8.32), searching...
1) Smart Array P420 Smart Array P420 in Slot 4 (6.64)
Select which devices to flash [#,#-#,(A)ll,(N)one]> A
Flashing Smart Array P420 in Slot 4 [ 6.64 -> 8.32 ]
Deferred flashes will be performed on next system reboot
============ Summary ============
Smart Component Finished

Summary Messages
================
Reboot needed to activate 1 new FW image

Exit Status: 1
Deferred flashes will be performed on next system reboot
A reboot is required to complete update.
```

After the reboot, I can check the new firmware version installed is fine:

```
#   ssacli ctrl all show detail

Smart Array P420 in Slot 4
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 4
   Serial Number: PDSXK0BRH5W034
   Cache Serial Number: PBKUC0BRH5C5PT
   RAID 6 Status: Enabled
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: B
   Firmware Version: 8.32
   Firmware Supports Online Firmware Activation: False
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: Not Configured
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 1.0
   Total Cache Memory Available: 0.8
   Battery Backed Cache Size: 0.8
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   SSD Caching RAID5 WriteBack Enabled: False
   SSD Caching Version: 1
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True
   Spare Activation Mode: Activate on physical drive failure (default)
   Number of Ports: 2 Internal only
   Encryption: Not Set
   Driver Name: hpsa
   Driver Version: 3.4.20
   Driver Supports SSD Smart Path: True
   PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:02:00.0
   Port Max Phy Rate Limiting Supported: False
   Host Serial Number: CZ1416039K
   Sanitize Erase Supported: False
   Primary Boot Volume: None
   Secondary Boot Volume: None
```

But the problem is still the same:

```
# ssacli ctrl all show config
Smart Array P420 in Slot 4                (sn: PDSXK0BRH5W034)
   HP SAS Expander Card at Port 1I, Box 1, OK
   Port Name: 1I
   Port Name: 2I
   Unassigned
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:0 (port 1I:box 1:bay 0, SATA HDD, 4 TB, OK)
   Expander 380  (WWID: 500143801174B426, Port: 1I, Box: 1)
   HP SAS Expander Card SEP 378  (WWID: 500143801174B425, Port: 1I, Box: 1)
   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 379  (WWID: 5001438028F5637F)
```

As you can see, "physicaldrive" remains the same in all HDD disks. Please some help with this would be really appreciated. Thanks!